# Is it a telescopic inequality??

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

Let $a_{i}>0, i=1,2,3,...,n. a_{n+1}=a_{1}$. Prove that $$2\sum_{k=1}^n \frac {a_{k}^2}{a_{k}+a_{k+1}} \ge \sum_{k=1}^n a_k$$ I took the RHS to the LHS and simplified which gave me the following expression after which i don't know what to do :- $$\sum_{k=1}^n a_k\left(\frac {a_k-a_{k+1}}{a_k+a_{k+1}}\right)\ge 0$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put
$$S=\sum_{k=1}^n a_k\frac{a_k-a_{k+1}}{a_k+a_{k+1}}$$
and
$$T=\sum_{k=1}^n a_{k+1}\frac{a_k-a_{k+1}}{a_k+a_{k+1}}$$

Then:

$$S-T=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(a_k-a_{k+1})^2}{a_k+a_{k+1}}\geq 0$$
$$S+T=\sum(a_k-a_{k+1})=0$$
as $a_{n+1}=a_1$.

Now if we add, we get $2S\geq 0$ and we are done.

Answer (score 2):

$$2\frac{a_k^2}{a_k+a_{k+1}}-a_k=a_k\frac{a_k-a_{k+1}}{a_k+a_{k+1}}.$$

Clearly, there exist a $M>0$ such that for all $k=1,...,n$, $\frac{a_{k+1}+a_k}{a_k}\leq M$, therefore

$$\sum_{k=1}^n\left(2\frac{a_k^2}{a_k+a_{k+1}}-a_k\right)\geq \frac{1}{M}\sum_{k=1}^n(a_{k}-a_{k+1})=\frac{1}{M}\underbrace{(a_1-a_{n+1})}_{=0}=0$$
what conclude the proof.

Comment: (+1) Sweet !! this is possibly the best way considering OP's approach :)

Comment: Do you have used that $a_k-a_{k+1}\geq 0$ ?

Comment: of course not ! Noting tells you that this inequality is true.

Comment: @Kellenner It is not given in the question..

Comment: How do you do from $\frac{a_k}{a_k+a_{k+1}}\geq 1/M$ to $a_k\frac{a_k-a_{k+1}}{a_k+a_{k+1}}\geq  \frac{a_k-a_{k+1}}{M }$

Comment: considere $\sum_{k}a_kb_k$, if $b_k\geq \lambda$ for all $k$, thus  $$\sum_{k}a_kb_k\geq \lambda\sum_{k}a_k.$$

Comment: Take (in the comment above) $n=1$, $b_1=3$, $\lambda=2$ and $a_1=-1$.

Comment: actually you are right... Then I'm probably wrong... I'll think about it. Thanks,

Comment: You are welcome, sorry.

Comment: @Kelenner In the question it is given $a_i >0$ for $i=1,2,...,n$

Comment: @Abhishek Bakshi: but not that $a_k-a_{k+1}>0$, that is the point...

Comment: @Kelenner ...ohhh sorry...i didn't notice.. :-P